# Watson Bluemix: Failed to create app

Tags: ibm-watson, watson, ibm-cloud-tools

I wanted to deploy one of the starter-kit apps in Bluemix.
In the "create app" screen after choosing the app from starter-kit overview, I always get the error message which says: Failed to create app.
Since I know the dependencies of resources I deleted all my Services and Resources - but still it fails to deploy. May anybody help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, I would suggest you add more details related to your problem ex: screenshots, which version or bluemix etc. The more details you add the better the community can help you fix the problem.

Comment: What starter kit are you using, and what region are you trying to deploy to?